# Accessing a typedef globally

Tags: c, struct, header, typedef

I found some source code that I want to incorporate into a C program I am writing. Let's call it existing.c. This file contains a typedef for a struct that is required for a parameter to a function defined lower down in the file. I want to call this function in my file main.c. I know I could probably get access to the function by declaring a function prototype in main.c, but I will also need access to that struct definition to declare and call the function.

There is no .h file for existing.c, although I could of course make one, say existing.h. But if I put the typedef in existing.h, then it seems like I would have to put #include "existing.h" into existing.c, which does not seem correct from my understanding of header files. I thought their purpose was to make the code in a certain file available to other compilation units, and shouldn't be required by that file itself.

So I guess my main question is straightforward, how do I use the function defined in existing.c in my own file main.c? Can I do it without a header file, like by putting some kind of struct prototype in main.c, similar to a function prototype, or specify the struct as external or something along those lines?

Edit: I probably should have mentioned in my original post that one reason I was hoping to avoid using a header was so I could incorporate the existing.c file unaltered in case there are revisions of this source in the future. Judging from the answers this is not possible.

Comment: *I would have to put #include "existing.h" into existing.c, which does not seem correct from my knowledge of header files* -- then your "knowledge" of header files is seriously mistaken. *shouldn't be required by that file itself* -- it isn't *required*, but it is (by far) best practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if I put the typedef in existing.h, then it seems like I would have to put #include "existing.h" into existing.c, which does not seem correct from my knowledge of header files.

That is precisely the thing to do: move the `typedef` into the `existing.h` header, then include that header in both the `existing.c` and in your code.

> I thought their purpose was to make the code in a certain file available to other compilation units, and shouldn't be required by that file itself.

That is how the headers do their job - you include them both from the implementation file and from the code that uses that implementation.

Although it is possible to write a header that matches what was in the implementation, and use it without inclusion in the implementation file itself, this is not desirable: one reason why you include the header in the implementation is to let the compiler check the code against the function prototypes from the header, and produce errors for any discrepancies it may find.

Answer (score 3):

> then it seems like I would have to put #include "existing.h" into existing.c, which does not seem correct

That's the proper and correct way to do it.

You place declarations in a header file if more than one compilation unit needs those declarations, and the source code file containing the implementation is almost always one of the files you include the header file in.